# How to skip iteration in for loop if condition is met

Tags: r, loops, iteration, skip

I have code to turn the upper triangle of a matrix into a vector and store the values from this vector along with their original coordinates from the matrix into a data frame. 
How do I skip the for loop if the element in the vector is zero?

I have tried else statements and other attempts.

```
v <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),9,9)
t <- v[upper.tri(v,diag=T)]
tful <- t[t!=0]
df <- data.frame(FP1=rep(0,length(t)),FP2=rep(0,length(t)),tanimoto=rep(0,length(t)))
for (i in 1:length(t)){
  if (t[i]==0) next
  else {
      col_num <- floor(sqrt(2*i-7/4)+.5)
      row_num <- i-(.5*col_num^2-.5*col_num+1)+1
      df$FP1[i] <- row_num
      df$FP2[i] <- col_num
      df$tanimoto[i] <- v[row_num,col_num]
    }
}
```

I dont want any zeros in my data frame, and the loop to skip these values.
I understand the data frame needs to be smaller in rows but i am using this as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `next` is working fine to skip the current iteration of the loop.

You still get 0s in the final result because all values of `df` were initialized df to 0. When you skip the  iteration, they are not changed, so they remain 0. If you change the initialization to be NA values, you'll see that no 0s are added.

```
df <- data.frame(FP1=rep(NA,length(t)),FP2=rep(NA,length(t)),tanimoto=rep(NA,length(t)))
for (i in 1:length(t)){
  if (t[i]==0) next
  else {
      col_num <- floor(sqrt(2*i-7/4)+.5)
      row_num <- i-(.5*col_num^2-.5*col_num+1)+1
      df$FP1[i] <- row_num
      df$FP2[i] <- col_num
      df$tanimoto[i] <- v[row_num,col_num]
    }
}
df
#    FP1 FP2 tanimoto
# 1    1   1        1
# 2    1   2        1
# 3    2   2        1
# 4    1   3        1
# 5    2   3        1
# 6    3   3        1
# 7   NA  NA       NA
# 8    2   4        1
# 9    3   4        1
# 10   4   4        1
# 11  NA  NA       NA
# ...
```

A simple modification would be to filter your data frame as a last step: `df = df[df$tanimoto != 0, ]`, or if you switch to `NA`, `df = na.omit(df)`.

We could also create a non-looping solution:

```
v1 = v != 0 
df2 = data.frame(FP1 = row(v)[v1], FP2 = col(v)[v1], tanimoto = v[v1])
df2 = subset(df2, FP1 <= FP2)
df2
#    FP1 FP2 tanimoto
# 1    1   1        1
# 7    1   2        1
# 8    2   2        1
# 13   1   3        1
# 14   2   3        1
# 15   3   3        1
# 20   2   4        1
# 21   3   4        1
# 22   4   4        1
# 27   3   5        1
# 28   4   5        1
# 29   5   5        1
# 33   1   6        1
# 34   4   6        1
# 35   5   6        1
# ...
```

Comment: when making the diagonal of a matrix a vector, the row_num and col_num gives the coordinates the element of the vector would be in the original matrix.

Comment: It just seems like a really complicated formula for something simple - I'd be wary of bugs or edge cases. The non-looping approach is clearer to me and therefore feels safer. (Probably more efficient, too.)

Comment: I agree. I have a large matrix and your code instantly did what I wanted it to do. My loop took forever. Thanks again.